# Keras/Tensorflow: model.predict() returns a list. How do I match the output with my class names?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, cnn

I have a CNN built in Keras. I have saved it and am now using the `model.predict()` function to make predictions from it. Whenever I run the following code,

```
def prediction(path):
    import keras
    from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array 
    from keras.models import load_model
    import PIL
    import numpy as np
    
    img = load_img(path)
    img = img.resize((224, 224))
    img = img_to_array(img) 

    img = img.reshape( -1,224, 224,3)

    model = load_model('model1.h5')
    pred = model.predict(img)

    return pred

print(prediction('/path/to/image/')
```

I get an output like this:

`[[7.578206e-37 1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00]]`

I am doing transfer learning using resnet50 with imagenet weights and [here](https://pastebin.com/GtyP2icA) is the `model.summary()`.

I have 4 classes. How do I find out where each prediction belongs?

I have looked [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/36238/what-does-the-output-of-model-predict-function-from-keras-mean) as well but it doesn't seem to help me.

Thanks

Comment: In your last dense layer, I show that dense layer output shape 4. But you mention that you have 2 classes.

Comment: Oops, I was doing 2 classes earlier, then 4. The 2 just stuck to my mind. Sorry for that, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model prediction output is a bunch of probabilities. In order to get category name you need use following snippet. It calculates the argmax of predicions and give it to CLASSES list:

```
print(CLASSES[np.argmax(predictions)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Keras included in their library to predict the class label. You can get the class label directly by using `model.predict_classes(img)`.

Ref: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/40415/109134